# Spring Sleuth integration for Apache Camel

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

Is there any Sleuth integration for Apache Camel in the wild?
(with support for not only the correlation id but also the Span stuff)

Answer (score 4):

I created a [spring-cloud-sleuth-camel library](https://bitbucket.org/charlbrink/spring-cloud-sleuth-camel) for spring boot applications. Just add to the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

As an option this lib could be used - https://github.com/Playtika/sleuth-camel Just including this dependency will do the job. Basically it will wrap all your camel routes in spring context with Spring Sleuth interceptors.

So in case you have 2 services connecting to each other via some camel route as a result you will have next trace on zipkin: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've done sth like this in the micro-infra-spring project - https://github.com/4finance/micro-infra-spring/tree/master/micro-infra-camel/src/main/java/com/ofg/infrastructure/camel . Since I'm no longer maintaining it I can't really say if it's still working properly. You can take that code and check it out yourself :P

Comment: I had a look already but it does cover only the propagation of the correlationId - and in way that is not 100% compatible anymore with Sleuth's current approach. I'm more looking at something like http://camel.apache.org/camel-zipkin but hooked into the Sleuth infrastructure.

Comment: But actually what else do you need? Over there AFAIR we're passing through the Camel's route information about tracing context. Then if you have Sleuth Zipkin on the classpath, when the span is closed, then it will be sent to Zipkin.

Comment: A new span should be started for instance when the exchange is sent to another endpoint (like a remote http call for instance).

Comment: Ah ok - so you're saying that it's missing all the RPC annotations. You're right! Indeed what's there in micro-infra is very primitive in terms of support. :/ So I think that the answer is no but from what I remember someone on Twitter mentioned (I think it's the author of camel-zipkin) that some work on Sleuth + Camel will be done

Comment: Nice - could you point me to some more information about that ?

Comment: Only this - https://twitter.com/donovancmuller/status/819979508128288768 - I know that's not too much ;)

Answer (score 0):

Available as of Camel 2.18

The camel-zipkin component is used for tracing and timing incoming and outgoing Camel messages using zipkin. Events (span) are captured for incoming and outgoing messages being sent to/from Camel.

To enable camel-zipkin you need to configure first:

```
ZipkinTracer zipkin = new ZipkinTracer();

// Configure the scribe span collector with the hostname and port for the Zipkin Collector Server 
zipkin.setSpanCollector(new ScribeSpanCollector("192.168.90.100", 9410);

// ...then add zipkin to the CamelContext
zipkin.init(camelContext);
```

This will the trace all incoming and outgoing messages in Camel routes.

More info here:
http://camel.apache.org/camel-zipkin